# How to extract data after equality sign?

Tags: php, regex

I wrote this regex by far but I can't get the correct data from :

Some text: TST = Data I need, TSA = More that I need to compare,
SMT = more that that I need

It's 2-3 capital letters before equality sign and then data for it until comma.

```
preg_match_all("/Some\s+text:\s+(?:([A-Z]{2,3})(?:\s+\=(\s\w+)*))(?:\,\s+([A-Z]{2,3})(?:\s+\=(\s\w+)*))*/mi" , $input_lines, $output_array);
```

Regex extracts(text, TST, need, SMT, need) but I'm trying to get:

> 0.text 1.TST 2.Data I need 3.TSA 4.More that I need to compare 5.SMT 6.more that that I need

Can someone please explain what mistakes I'm doing and how should I correct this regex?

Comment: how does "Data" look like? Also please go over your post once more, since it's very confusing.

Comment: I'd suggest this: [`(?:(Some\s+text):\s*|(?!^)\G)\s*([A-Z]{2,3})\s+\=\s*((?:\w+\s?)+),?`](https://regex101.com/r/mM7fL2/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
([A-Z]{2,3})\s=\s([^,]+)
```

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/Rg2DAGtKUU)

Here `\s` can be replace with `\s*`.

Answer (score 3):

Given your original description: `It's 2-3 capital letters before equality sign and then data for it until comma.`, you can construct a relatively simple expression like so: `[A-Z]{2,3}\s*=\s*(.+?)(,|$)` (example available [here](https://regex101.com/r/bJ3nV3/1)).

This should expect to find 2 or 3 upper case letters, followed by 0 or more white spaces, followed by an equality sign, followed by 0 or more white spaces followed by some text. It will stop matching either when it finds a comma or the end of the string.

This should capture the data you are after into regular expression groups (should be within `$output_array`).

Comment: in your explantation, there is missing: "followed by an equality sign" between "followed by 0 or more white spaces, followed by 0 or more white spaces" :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex: `([A-Z]{2,3}\s=\s)([\w\s]+)`

Since you do not tell us what kind of data is stored in these variables, we can't help you with these. I'm using `[\w\s]+`, but you will need to tweak this.

Your fields are in match's group 1.

Live demo here at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mE4fV6/2)